# weird issue with css position in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

On this website http://rwl.rwlwater.com/ the news scroller at the bottom, after the 3 blurbs ..is not working fine in Internet explorer 7. The controller buttons are not moving if I edit the number of posts.. It's working fine in IE9, chrome, firefox, safari, etc, the issue is just with internet explorer 7.

I tried a few things, but couldn't solve it myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Provide the *relevant* code.** Nobody wants to sift through your entire website to find your issue. Help us, so we can help you.

Comment: The code for what? It's the news section and the controller buttons are not going down when I use for example 6 posts in the news scroller. it works fine with 4, but it should move down automatically if I have more posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CSS property 'zoom: 1' to the #controllers2 button or #blog2

This sets the IE property hasLayout to true and allows it to be positioned using absolute positioning.

It's a classic IE bug.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. when it first loads it loads the first 4 posts and then it extends to 6 posts, but the controllers are not moving down

Comment: What do you mean by the controllers are not moving down? What is a controller in this context??? In my IE7 browser I can click up and down and it moves the list of items either upwards or downwards. Which part of this functionality isn't working?

Comment: there are the two buttons that control the scroller... the arrows... When you first load the website, the box contains 4 elements and a half of the 5th element.... After it loads everything, it loads the 5th and the 6th one, the background extends but the arrows are not moving down under the box. That's my problem.

Comment: try zoom: 0 on the containing element #blog2

Comment: Do you have IE7 developer toolbar installed??? All I did was inspect the element, dynamically add the zoom: 1 property using the toolbar and it looks like it works. Can you try doing this with the toolbar? On the currently live and active site? It's working on my end.

Comment: zoom: 1 to what? to #blog2? You said zoom:0 in the previous message... thank you for helping me!

Comment: I don't think it matters but try either one. I first added zoom to #controllers2 and it worked. And then I tried to add zoom to #blog2 and it also worked.

Comment: I added zoom: 1 to all of them but it still doesn't work. can you check it with the developer tools now? I'm on mac os x and that's why I m quite limited

Comment: I fixed it, it was because of the height of the recentscroll2 class, it had a value by default and that was the problem! Now it works perfectly ! Thank you!